# Ordenar um array em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Olá. Estou com um problema e não estou conseguindo resolver.
EU tenho um texto dentro de um array com várias letras aleatórias.

Ex:"vwv rhjs vqgvcq pjdvb gjpsmc jsm zhctgvl jwgbbs" e por assim vai, são 600 palavras.

Eu preciso ordenar as palavras em ordem alfabética, porém não na ordem do nosso alfabeto. Mas esse alfaberto personalizado,a ordem das letras é 
"k,b,w,r,q,d,n,f,x,j,m,l,v,h,t,c,g,z,p,s.

Já tentei passar tudo para float, e tentar ordenar com o Sort(), mas não deu certo. Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Texto dentro de um array? Ou cada palavra é um elemento da array?

Comment: Então, o texto nem está num array. É apenas um texto.. Eu que coloquei ele em um array...

Comment: Tá faltando letra aí na sua ordem

Comment: No caso estão faltando as letras "aeiouy"

Comment: Entao... mas esse alfabeto personalizado, são só essas letras... não tem as demais.

Comment: Mas as demais aparecem antes ou depois das que mencionou ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aí você tem que usar uma função comparando os itens de acordo com o valor da posição das letras na string que você ordenou. Usando `.indexOf()` você acha a posição da primeira letra no índice `[0]`, mas você terá que quebrar o texto da array para usar o `.sort()`:

```js
var string = ["sap vwv rhjs vqgvcq pjdvb pwzs gjpsmc jsm zhctgvl jwgbbs pwz"];
var alfa = "k,b,w,r,q,d,n,f,x,j,m,l,v,h,t,c,g,z,p,s";
string[0] = string[0].split(" ").sort(function(a, b){
   
   // faz uma comparação de tamanho da palavra para
   // fazer o laço "for" mais abaixo pela palavra que for maior
   var len = a.length > b.length || a.length == b.length ? a.length : b.length;
   
   // só faz o "return" quando uma letra for diferente da outra
   for(var x=0; x < len; x++){
      if(a[x] != b[x]) return alfa.indexOf(a[x])-alfa.indexOf(b[x]);
   }
   
}).join(" ");
console.log(string);
```

O `string[0].split(" ")` quebra o texto do índice `[0]` da array pelo espaço em branco.

O `alfa.indexOf(a[x])-alfa.indexOf(b[x])` compara a posição das letras de cada palavra pela anterior na string `alfa` e monta um novo array organizado, e o `.join(" ")` converte em string separando os itens da array por um espaço, atribuindo um novo valor ao `string[0]`, agora com as palavras na ordem.

Comment: Então, deu certo para a primeira letra... Ele ordenou, mas quando a varias palavras iniciando com a mesma letra, ele nao ordena na ordem correta.

Comment: To quebrando a cabeça aqui o fds de semana interiro, nao consegui. o Mais proximo que conseguir foi transformar tudo para int com o indexof, e depois tentar comparar o com sort() usando uma function => p1-p2. Porém, quando transformo tudo em numero, vira um array assim : [1,12,13,2] e quando peço pro sort comparar dois arrays dessa forma, ele nao consegue... mas se eu juntar o array, [12 2 12 2] ai o sort entendo que é tudo um numero só.

Comment: Veja agora.....

Comment: Show de bola.. Obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: TRanquilo! Saiba como agradecer [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Crie um dicionário das letras na ordem que você quer dentro de um `array`;
- Crie um `array` com as letras normais do alfabeto;
- Separe as palavras da frase que você quer com [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) por espaço;
- Indexe as palavras resultantes utilizando o dicionário criado anteriormente, assim você terá um `array` com palavras transformadas em números. No seu exemplo você terá o seguinte:

  ```
  [[12,2,12], [3,13,9,19], [12,4,16,12,15,4], [18,9,5,12,1], [16,9,18,19,10,15], [9,19,10], [17,13,15,14,16,12,11], [9,2,16,1,1,19]]
  ```
- Faça a equivalencia entre os índices gerados e o alfabeto normal para obter uma lista de palavras equivalentes. No seu exemplo você terá o seguinte:

  ```
  ['mcm', 'dnjt', 'meqmpe', 'sjfmb', 'qjstkp', 'jtk', 'rnpoqml', 'jcqbbt']
  ```
- Utilize o [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) para ordenar as palavras resultantes, obtendo:

  ```
  ['dnjt', 'jcqbbt', 'jtk', 'mcm', 'meqmpe', 'qjstkp', 'rnpoqml', 'sjfmb']
  ```
- Indexe a equivalencia ordenada e utilize o `array` dicionário para transformar os índices em palavras novamente, obtendo o seguinte resultado após unir o `array` resultante em uma nova frase:

  ```
  rhjs jwgbbs jsm vwv vqgvcq gjpsmc zhctgvl pjdvb
  ```

```js
const DICIONARIO = ['k', 'b', 'w', 'r', 'q', 'd', 'n', 'f', 'x', 'j', 'm', 'l', 'v', 'h', 't', 'c', 'g', 'z', 'p', 's'];
const ALFABETO = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm','n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

const indexar = (referencia, palavra) => [...palavra].map((letra) => referencia.indexOf(letra));

const traduzir = (indices) => indices.map((indice) => DICIONARIO[parseInt(indice, 10)]).join('');

const ordenar = (frase) => {
  const indices = frase
    .split(' ')
    .map((palavra) => indexar(DICIONARIO, palavra));

  const equivalentes = indices.map((indice) => indice.map(posicao => ALFABETO[posicao]).join(''));

  equivalentes.sort();

  return equivalentes
    .map((palavra) => indexar(ALFABETO, palavra))
    .map(traduzir)
    .join(' ');
};

console.log(ordenar('vwv rhjs vqgvcq pjdvb gjpsmc jsm zhctgvl jwgbbs'));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @RodolfoMori se a resposta te ajudou de um +1 nelas